# How to write a unit test for a function that does coordinate transforms and perspective projection

Tags: python, unit-testing, image-processing, coordinate-transformation, perspectivecamera

I have a function that transforms some 3d points to the coordinates system of a camera, then projects those points to the camera image. I am struggeling to find a way how to make this testable. This function uses other simpler functions that perform one task (like coordinate transform etc) and have tests already.

What comes to my mind now is to take this function, used to perform the projection, then check by myself if the result makes sense by looking at where the points were projected on the rgb image and if they match the object they represent (eg. 3d points representing a ball will cover the pixels representing the ball in the image after being projected). I could then use those few real world data examples in the unit test. But this would mean that I have to upload to the git repository along with the tests.

I could also generate virtual data but that is not easy to check if the projection was correct because I would need that same function first to generate an rgb image that matches the 3d points. It seems to me it is a kind of chicken an egg problem here.

I am using Python and Numpy.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Find a different method of verifying the output is correct, then use that to test your code. You can't test code if you don't understand the exact requirements.

Comment: This isn't unique to corodinate transforms and projections. There is no magic bullet here.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Until now I was very data driven, projecting points and looking by myself if they land on the correct spot in the color image. "FInd a different method of verifying the output" is exactly where I am stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's two things at play here, care not to confound them:

For one, there's unit tests. The unit tests should be as simple as possible and cover the smallest possible code at a time. Split the transformation in the simplest steps, give each one its own function, then you can make up simple examples containing 0's, 1's, pi and so on. These samples can be checked by a human with pen and paper.

The other part are regression tests. You made sure that the transformation is doing the right thing currently by doing a visual check. Then just pick a few data points, possibly some border points (or some interesting limits), and use them in a test. There's no reason to upload much data to git, just add a few textual lines containing the input and output data in your test code. This will take more effort to follow with pen and paper, but you confirmed the correctness visually.

Comment: As I mentioed before, the problematic function is just a combination of simpler already tested functions for convenience of usage as a library where one function will do it all in one line. Would you suggest to just remove it and call the other functions sequentially whenever they are needed?

Comment: No, I'd keep the library function. Ensure that it is doing the correct thing, through visual checks or computing the inverse function (getting back the original data). Then add a few synthetic or real data points as a regression test for this function.